# Effects of DC offset and loading at the input of an envelope detector (simple diode demodulator)

Tags: diodes, amplitude-modulation, demodulation

I am currently designing an AM radio. I am utilizing a diode demodulator

[image]

(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6c/Simple_envelope_detector.svg)

to extract the envelope of my carrier signal. I am using a 1N34A germanium diode, which has a forward voltage of 0.3 volts. I would like to know what are the constraints on the DC point at the input of the demodulator. I believe it is necessary to have an offset of 0 V so as to avoid following the input signal at the wrong moment, but I am not entirely sure. Could I benefit from a DC offset? I'm also wondering about the effects of loading on my demodulator, since I will be connecting a voltage amplifier stage before it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often a small DC bias can help improve detection efficiency. Something around 100mV for a germanium diode. Often the DC bias is shared with the transistor bias such as in this design.

[image: Simple Am receiver]

A germanium diode actually starts conducting at much less than 300mV [image: Germanium Diode characteristics] so it can detect RF of only a few millivolts.

> I'm also wondering about the effects of loading on my demodulator,
>   since I will be connecting a voltage amplifier stage before it. Thank
>   you!

Don't you mean after it, not before?

Yes you do have to be careful about loading the demodulator with the following stages.  It should have a high input impedance relative to the RC filter after the diode.

What type of receiver are you designing?  A TRF(Tuned Radio Frequency) or Superhet (Supersonic Heterodyne)?